# R-Store results from model into a matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I look for answers, but they do not provide what I am looking for. I am running some simple models and I am trying to get the results (LRT mainly) into a table or matrix, so I can present them better. However, the command for does not let me do that, which is odd, given other programming languages do it very easily.

In the last sentence, either if I substitute a[j] or whatever, it still says  object a not found. How can I override this using for? Thank you.

```
li<-array(c(716, 207,79,25,819,186,67,22), c(2,2,2))
dimnames(li)<-list(c("Normal","High"),c("N BP", "H BP"),c("A","B"))
#General Model with three variables and no interactions.
a1<-loglin(li,list(1,2,3))
#Model with XY,Z
a2<-loglin(li,list(c(1,2),3))
#Model with XZ,Y
a3<-loglin(li,list(c(1,3),2))
#Model with X,ZY
a4<-loglin(li,list(c(2,3),1))
#Model with XY,XZ
a5<-loglin(li,list(c(1,2),c(1,3)))
#Model with YZ,XZ
a6<-loglin(li,list(c(2,3),c(1,3)))
#Model with XY,ZY
a7<-loglin(li,list(c(1,2),c(2,3)))

tabi<-matrix(data=c(0),nrow=10,ncol=2)
for (j in 1:7) {
  i<-j
tabi[i,1]<-a[i]$lrt
}
```

Side note. I have tried writing "ai", "aj", "a[i]", etc. it does not work.

Comment: `a[1]` is not the same as `a1`

Comment: I know that, I tried with all different combinations and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who want  simpler answer and had the same as I, here is a simpler way which involves less coding:

Basically just create a list and define your models as a list by adding [[]], and that's it. Run your code regularly.

```
a<-list()
#General Model with three variables and no interactions.
a[[1]]<-loglin(li,list(1,2,3))
#Model with XY,Z
a[[2]]<-loglin(li,list(c(1,2),3))
#Model with XZ,Y
a[[3]]<-loglin(li,list(c(1,3),2))
#Model with X,ZY
a[[4]]<-loglin(li,list(c(2,3),1))
#Model with XY,XZ
a[[5]]<-loglin(li,list(1:2,1:3))
#Model with YZ,XZ
a[[6]]<-loglin(li,list(2:3,1:3))
#Model with XY,ZY
a[[7]]<-loglin(li,list(1:2,2:3))

tabi<-matrix(data=c(0),nrow=10,ncol=2)

for (j in 1:7) {
  i<-j
tabi[i,1]<-a[[j]]$pearson
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have all these models in your workspace you can extract then with `mget`, which returns a list, and then loop through this to extract the `lrt`.

So for your example,

```
sapply(mget(ls(pattern="a\\d")), "[", "lrt")
```

where `mget(ls(pattern="a\\d"))` grabs the data from the global env with the pattern `a`number, and `sapply` loops through this list to extract.

As an alternative workflow, rather than having lots of models floating about in your workspace you could store the models in a list.

So store the parameters in a list

```
para <- list(list(1,2,3), list(c(1,2),3), list(c(1,3),2))
```

Then loop through these applying the model

```
lst <- lapply(para, function(x) loglin(li, x))
```

This stores each model in `lst`. You could of used `loglin(li, x)$lrt` above if you just want this item. Otherwise you can loop through as before to extract it.

```
sapply(lst, "[", "lrt")
```

---

Note about your code is that `a[1]` is not the same as `a1`

Comment: Thank you. I will think of this as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Can use paste to concatenate a, and the value of i in your loop to get a1, a2, a3 etc as a string and then use eval and parse to evaluate it as a variable.

```
tabi<-matrix(data=c(0),nrow=10,ncol=2)
for (i in 1:7) {

  tabi[i,1]<-eval(parse(text = paste("a",i,sep="")))$lrt

}
```